# Make a transformed element remain static while other elements animate

Tags: after-effects

We have a record button that needs to transform the middle element from a circle at rest, to a square when recording, as the outside rings pulse. We are having trouble getting the square to stay static while the rest of the button animates.

Seeking advice on how get the circle to stay a square while recording and turn back to a circle when done. Working in After Effects to generate Lottie code. Code below. Thank you!

```json
{
  "v": "5.6.5",
  "fr": 60,
  "ip": 0,
  "op": 20,
  "w": 56,
  "h": 56,
  "nm": "Record_button",
  "ddd": 0,
  "assets": [],
  "layers": [
    {
      "ddd": 0,
      "ind": 1,
      "ty": 4,
      "nm": "Record_inner_ring",
      "sr": 1,
      "ks": {
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 100,
          "ix": 11
        },
        "r": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 0,
          "ix": 10
        },
        "p": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            28,
            28,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 2
        },
        "a": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 1
        },
        "s": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            100,
            100,
            100
          ],
          "ix": 6
        }
      },
      "ao": 0,
      "shapes": [
        {
          "ty": "gr",
          "it": [
            {
              "ind": 0,
              "ty": "sh",
              "ix": 1,
              "ks": {
                "a": 1,
                "k": [
                  {
                    "i": {
                      "x": 0.667,
                      "y": 1
                    },
                    "o": {
                      "x": 0.333,
                      "y": 0
                    },
                    "t": 0,
                    "s": [
                      {
                        "i": [
                          [
                            -10.99,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            -10.99
                          ],
                          [
                            10.99,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            10.99
                          ]
                        ],
                        "o": [
                          [
                            10.99,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            10.99
                          ],
                          [
                            -10.99,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            -10.99
                          ]
                        ],
                        "v": [
                          [
                            0,
                            -19.9
                          ],
                          [
                            19.9,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            19.9
                          ],
                          [
                            -19.9,
                            0
                          ]
                        ],
                        "c": true
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "t": 19,
                    "s": [
                      {
                        "i": [
                          [
                            0,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            0
                          ]
                        ],
                        "o": [
                          [
                            0,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            0
                          ]
                        ],
                        "v": [
                          [
                            0,
                            -19.9
                          ],
                          [
                            19.9,
                            0
                          ],
                          [
                            0,
                            19.9
                          ],
                          [
                            -19.9,
                            0
                          ]
                        ],
                        "c": true
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "ix": 2
              },
              "nm": "Path 1",
              "mn": "ADBE Vector Shape - Group",
              "hd": false
            },
            {
              "ty": "fl",
              "c": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0.961000025272,
                  0.753000020981,
                  0.259000003338,
                  1
                ],
                "ix": 4
              },
              "o": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 100,
                "ix": 5
              },
              "r": 1,
              "bm": 0,
              "nm": "Fill 1",
              "mn": "ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill",
              "hd": false
            },
            {
              "ty": "tr",
              "p": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix": 2
              },
              "a": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix": 1
              },
              "s": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  100,
                  100
                ],
                "ix": 3
              },
              "r": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 45,
                "ix": 6
              },
              "o": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 100,
                "ix": 7
              },
              "sk": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 0,
                "ix": 4
              },
              "sa": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 0,
                "ix": 5
              },
              "nm": "Transform"
            }
          ],
          "nm": "Record_inner_ring",
          "np": 2,
          "cix": 2,
          "bm": 0,
          "ix": 1,
          "mn": "ADBE Vector Group",
          "hd": false
        }
      ],
      "ip": 0,
      "op": 21,
      "st": 0,
      "bm": 0
    },
    {
      "ddd": 0,
      "ind": 2,
      "ty": 4,
      "nm": "Record_grey_inner_ring",
      "sr": 1,
      "ks": {
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 100,
          "ix": 11
        },
        "r": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 0,
          "ix": 10
        },
        "p": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            28,
            28,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 2
        },
        "a": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 1
        },
        "s": {
          "a": 1,
          "k": [
            {
              "i": {
                "x": [
                  0.833,
                  0.833,
                  0.833
                ],
                "y": [
                  0.833,
                  0.833,
                  1
                ]
              },
              "o": {
                "x": [
                  0.167,
                  0.167,
                  0.167
                ],
                "y": [
                  0.167,
                  0.167,
                  0
                ]
              },
              "t": 0,
              "s": [
                100,
                100,
                100
              ]
            },
            {
              "t": 19,
              "s": [
                92,
                92,
                100
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ix": 6
        }
      },
      "ao": 0,
      "shapes": [
        {
          "ty": "gr",
          "it": [
            {
              "d": 1,
              "ty": "el",
              "s": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  48,
                  48
                ],
                "ix": 2
              },
              "p": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix": 3
              },
              "nm": "Ellipse Path 1",
              "mn": "ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse",
              "hd": false
            },
            {
              "ty": "fl",
              "c": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0.224000006914,
                  0.224000006914,
                  0.224000006914,
                  1
                ],
                "ix": 4
              },
              "o": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 100,
                "ix": 5
              },
              "r": 1,
              "bm": 0,
              "nm": "Fill 1",
              "mn": "ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill",
              "hd": false
            },
            {
              "ty": "tr",
              "p": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix": 2
              },
              "a": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix": 1
              },
              "s": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  100,
                  100
                ],
                "ix": 3
              },
              "r": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 0,
                "ix": 6
              },
              "o": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 100,
                "ix": 7
              },
              "sk": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 0,
                "ix": 4
              },
              "sa": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 0,
                "ix": 5
              },
              "nm": "Transform"
            }
          ],
          "nm": "Record_inner_ring",
          "np": 2,
          "cix": 2,
          "bm": 0,
          "ix": 1,
          "mn": "ADBE Vector Group",
          "hd": false
        }
      ],
      "ip": 0,
      "op": 22,
      "st": 0,
      "bm": 0
    },
    {
      "ddd": 0,
      "ind": 3,
      "ty": 4,
      "nm": "Record_white_outer_ring",
      "sr": 1,
      "ks": {
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 100,
          "ix": 11
        },
        "r": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 0,
          "ix": 10
        },
        "p": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            28,
            28,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 2
        },
        "a": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            0,
            0,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 1
        },
        "s": {
          "a": 1,
          "k": [
            {
              "i": {
                "x": [
                  0.833,
                  0.833,
                  0.833
                ],
                "y": [
                  0.833,
                  0.833,
                  1
                ]
              },
              "o": {
                "x": [
                  0.167,
                  0.167,
                  0.167
                ],
                "y": [
                  0.167,
                  0.167,
                  0
                ]
              },
              "t": 0,
              "s": [
                100,
                100,
                100
              ]
            },
            {
              "t": 19,
              "s": [
                92,
                92,
                100
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ix": 6
        }
      },
      "ao": 0,
      "shapes": [
        {
          "ty": "gr",
          "it": [
            {
              "d": 1,
              "ty": "el",
              "s": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  56,
                  56
                ],
                "ix": 2
              },
              "p": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix": 3
              },
              "nm": "Ellipse Path 1",
              "mn": "ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse",
              "hd": false
            },
            {
              "ty": "fl",
              "c": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0.847000002861,
                  0.847000002861,
                  0.847000002861,
                  1
                ],
                "ix": 4
              },
              "o": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 100,
                "ix": 5
              },
              "r": 1,
              "bm": 0,
              "nm": "Fill 1",
              "mn": "ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill",
              "hd": false
            },
            {
              "ty": "tr",
              "p": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0.083,
                  -0.163
                ],
                "ix": 2
              },
              "a": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  0,
                  0
                ],
                "ix": 1
              },
              "s": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": [
                  100,
                  100
                ],
                "ix": 3
              },
              "r": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 0,
                "ix": 6
              },
              "o": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 100,
                "ix": 7
              },
              "sk": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 0,
                "ix": 4
              },
              "sa": {
                "a": 0,
                "k": 0,
                "ix": 5
              },
              "nm": "Transform"
            }
          ],
          "nm": "Record_outer_ring",
          "np": 2,
          "cix": 2,
          "bm": 0,
          "ix": 1,
          "mn": "ADBE Vector Group",
          "hd": false
        }
      ],
      "ip": 0,
      "op": 22,
      "st": 0,
      "bm": 0
    }
  ],
  "markers": []
}
```